# Getting right values from JSON using Python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have this json file

https://pastebin.com/embed_js/PknXEGq2

and here is my code so far

```
import json

data = json.load(open('data.json'))

Product = []
Products = []

def get_products():
    query_one = data['Bundles']
    for first in query_one:
        Product = first.get('Product') or []
        for i in Product:
            for key, val in i.items():
                if key == None :
                    print(i.index(key) + key)
                elif key is False:
                 print("Error")
                else:
                 print("You can buy " + str(key) + " at our store at " + str(val))
                 
    Products = data['Bundles']
    var_two = Products
    for second in Products:
        var_two = second.get('Products')
        for j in var_two:
            for key_two, val_two in j.items():
                if key_two == None:
                    print(j.index(key_two) + key_two)
                elif key_two is False:
                    print("Error")
                else:
                    print("You can buy " + str(key_two) + " at our store at " + str(val_two))
    return ""

get_products()
```

The problem is that I'm not able to get the right values and keys for some, so how I can specify the right elements (Product Name and Price) I want to get from the json file

The result must be

> You can buy Tommee Tippee Ctn Transition Cup at our store at 12

Comment: Can you add an example of the actual output you need?

Comment: You can buy Tommee Tippee Ctn Transition Cup at our store at 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your code. Please check whether it fulfills your task :

```
import json

data = json.load(open('data.json'))

ignore_values = ["Size 6-12m & 1-2y", " 6-11kg Girl"]

def get_products():
    bundles = data.get("Bundles")
    for bundle in bundles:
        
        products = bundle.get("Product")
        if products:
            for product in products:
                product_name = product.get("Name", '')
                product_price = product.get("Price", '')
                if any(ignore_value in product_name for ignore_value in ignore_values):
                    for ignore_value in ignore_values:
                        product_name = product_name.replace(ignore_value, '')
                print("You can buy {0} Ctn Transition Cup at our store at {1}".format(product_name, product_price))

        products = bundle.get("Products")
        if products:
            for product in products:
                product_name = product.get("Name", '')
                product_price = product.get("Price", '')
                if any(ignore_value in product_name for ignore_value in ignore_values):
                    for ignore_value in ignore_values:
                        product_name = product_name.replace(ignore_value, '')
                print("You can buy {0} Ctn Transition Cup at our store at {1}".format(product_name, product_price))
                 

            
get_products()
```

Comment: That really helped thanks,I have another question is it possible to remove "Size 6-12m & 1-2y" and " 6-11kg Girl" from some products, I mean the additional description in the name of these products

Comment: I updated the code. You can add what you need to remove into the `ignore_values` list and check.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
import sys
import os
data = json.load(open(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])+'/file.json'))

Product = []
Products = []

def get_products():
    query_one = data['Bundles']
    
    for first in query_one:
        Product = first.get('Product') or []
        for i in Product:
            name = ""
            price = ""
            for key, val in i.items():
            
                if key == None :
                    pass
                elif key=="Price":
                    price = val
                    
                elif key=="Name":
                    name = val
            print ("You can buy " + str(name) + " at the price  " + str(price))
                

get_products()
```

That the first Element and this is the output:

```
You can buy Tommee Tippee Ctn Transition Cup at the price  12
```